# Writing to the windows logs in Python

Tags: python, windows, logging

Is it possible to write to the windows logs in python?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yes, just use Windows Python Extension, as stated [here](http://www.ravenbrook.com/project/p4dti/master/design/win32-eventlog/).

```
import win32evtlogutil
win32evtlogutil.ReportEvent(ApplicationName, EventID, EventCategory,
                EventType, Inserts, Data, SID)
```

Comment: how do I install win32evtlogutil? pip install doesn't seem to do the job

Comment: install python for windows extensions (`pywin32`) @sorh